# Middleman - is it possible for one locale to inerit data from another locale?

Tags: ruby, middleman, static-site

We are using Middleman for our multi-lingual website. Just as described in the [Middleman localization guide](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/localization/) we use a mixture of storing translations in .yml files for each language (e.g. en.yml, es.yml etc.) and having localized templates (e.g. about.en.html.md).

The problem is that for some languages (such as English) there can be variations depending on the country - e.g. it makes sense to display currency in dollars for the US and pounds for the UK. We could modify our config.rb from this:

```
activate :i18n, :langs => [:en, :es, :fr], :mount_at_root => false
```

to this:

```
activate :i18n, :langs => [:en_us, :en_gb, :es, :fr], :mount_at_root => false
```

But this means there will be a lot of duplication in the locale files. Is it instead possible to configure Middleman so that both "en_us" and "en_gb" inherit from a root "en" template? If not what about writing a helper - would it be even possible to extend Middleman in such a way?